# How to Embed Custom Object Page Layout into Visual Force page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, page-layout

I have a One custom object(Used for searching purpose) and i want to  add that particular object's all the fields into  the visual force page what is the best way to do this  ?  I  need

```
Field name-Field Entry object
```

Style  for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all fields or particular fields of an object in visualforce page you need to take that object in standard controller and give a recordsetvar attribute anything.
In pageblocktable give the recordsetval as a value.for this you can go through following code.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" StandardController="Rule__c" recordSetVar="AList" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title=" All Accounts Available">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AList}" Var="B">
                    <apex:column value="{!B.Object__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!B.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

if it is useful for you please accept it and give kudo's.

Comment: i want to  design the  search form for given object  and you had provided me with the data value. you had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed a custom object standard page layout then you should use :

```
<apex:detail subject="id of record"/>
```